# Can I with SCTP use bindx/SCTP_SOCKOPT_BINDX_ADD after connecting?

Tags: linux, sctp

When using SCTP, after I have called bind() (but not bindx() / SCTP_SOCKOPT_BINDX_ADD) and after I have called connect(), can I then call bind() or use SCTP_SOCKOPT_BINDX_ADD?

E.g. -after- connecting, rather than after binding and before connecting, can I add additional local IP addresses (for multi-homing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC said:
Adding and removing addresses from a connected association is an
optional functionality. Implementations that do not support this
functionality should return -1 and set errno to EOPNOTSUPP.

But in linux, you can add/rem additional local ip addr after 
established connection.

Comment: Sorry the bounty took so long.  I had thought marking this the corret answer awarded the bounty.  Turns out I have to award it seperately.